# Turn on LEGO Mindstorms robot remotely

Tags: mindstorms, remote-control

I'm thinking to build a robot using either NXT or EV3, then I can control it remotely via WiFi or Bluetooth from my office! It's not difficult to write the controlling codes, but how can I turn the robot on remotely? Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know for a fact (from reading the EV3 schematics), the only way to turn on an EV3 is by pressing the center button.

Here are some ideas to work around this issue:

- Create another robot that presses the power button.
- Create a mechanical device that causes the center button to be pressed all of the time, then create a mechanism to switch battery power.
- Solder wires in parallel with the center button and attach this to a device, such as a relay, that can operate the center button electrically.